# Tools for downloading a Flash video file on Linux

Tags: linux, flash, fedora

How can I download a Flash video file from a website when using Linux (Fedora).
Can you suggest any tools on Linux to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FlashGet](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/220/) On Firefox should help you !

Comment: or Unplug for Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2254/

Comment: yeah stib, that one is also good.

Answer (score 2):

If the site is YouTube, the Python script [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) which is the package `youtube-dl` in Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Downloadhelper](http://www.downloadhelper.net/), although I wouldn't use it for conversion, just grabbing the FLV.

Comment: I use DownloadHelper for dloading flv file and FormatFactory for conversion process.

Answer (score 0):

If the sites you're thinking of are for instance YouTube or Dailymotion, [jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) should be fine.

Comment: Just keep in mind that, "JDownloader requires Java Runtime Enviroment (jre/jdk) 1.5 or higher. If possible, you should use the latest Java version"

Comment: Hm yeah, right. I only use it on Windows so it's simple there, on Linux it seems a bit more complicated apparently:
http://fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=232657
http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/887/installing-jdownloader-on-linux/
But the good thing with jDownloader is that you can choose the resolution of the video on download (on Youtube at least).

Comment: JDownloader is easy to install and works fine on Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice Firefox extension for this is [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/).

Answer (score 0):

open streaming site and watch it until finish (don't close the browser or the tabs)..

then, just go to dir /tmp n find file with randomized name n have icon like video...

if u find it, just copy and paste it to another dir (hint "yes" if question appear)...

thanks for linux, it read file type by file header, not by extension. so, a file with no extension can be recognized....

it work on my Fedora 14 with Firefox 3.6.13